# Winforms - Changing name of MDIParent Form from Child Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the Name (Text) header of the MDI Parent form depending on input from the user on one of the child forms.

I've tried this code:

```
frmMain main = (frmMain)this.MdiParent;
main.Text = "New Name";
```

But I get an object reference not set error.

Comment: Are you sure the form actually IS a child of `frmMain`? Check `this.MdiParent` for `null` before the assignment.

Comment: When are you trying to change the parent form?  Is it when the form is closed?  When a value in an input control changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.MdiParent.Text="New Name";
```

but I think you are trying to do this

```
Form child = new Form();
String formText = "Child ";
child.Text = formText;
child.MdiParent = this;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244121/how-to-display-string-on-title-bar-on-mdiparent-form-from-login-form

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are attempting to do that in the child Form's constructor. The MdiParent property can't be set until after the constructor completes.

Overload the OnLoad method in the child Form and change the parent's Text property there.

Comment: Given that it seems he wants to set the text based on user input it seems unlikely the code would be in the constructor.

Comment: The above code trying to change the Main forms name is in an OnClick event of a button on the Child Form

Comment: @PJW Then Anon ymous is probably correct, you didn't set the MdiParent property when you created the child Form.